# Spring data jpa : how to retrieve data using @ElementCollection?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Here is a part of Files.java

```
@Entity(name="files")
public class Files {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> filenames= new ArrayList<String>();

    //<< getter and setter >>
}
```

it is correctly created the table 'Files' and 'Files_filenames' on mySql

and I can put data there on Controller with it

```
Files files = new Files();
files.setTitle(ufile.getTitle());
files.setFilenames(Arrays.asList(ufile.getFilename().split(",")));
```

so far, everything looks ok

However, when I try to get the data from the database, the filename always returns something like 'persistentbag' not ArrayList.

I would like to know how to get ArrayList from the database

I'm using Spring data JPA using Hibernate as a Jpa vendor.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[`PersistentBag`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentBag.html) *is a* `List` (i.e., it implements `List`), therefore you can use it as a regular `List`. There is no need to care about actual implementation of that `List` in this case.